# Why prototype.js causing jquery slider to not working in ie 9 and ie8?

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript

In my product detail page i have integrated a slider for related products. It works well in all browser except ie 9 and ie 8, works in ie 10.

When **i removed prototype.js** from page.xml **it works** well in all browsers. Why this issue occuring any solution to this problem?

I am not getting any error in browser console.

The plugin i used is [caroufredsel](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/). 
In my related.phtml file used following code,

```
<script  src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js');?>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#block-related').carouFredSel({
    circular: false,
    infinite: false,
    auto    : false,
    prev    : {button: "#foo2_prev",key: "left"},
    next    : { button: "#foo2_next",key:"right"
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: the product detail page already contains jquery.js added via cloud zoom extension. when i updated this jquery.js to latest version it began to work in ie also

Comment: Please add your fix as an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you add `noConflict` right after the included jQuery library? ([read more](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/))

By adding

```
<script type="text/ajavscript">
jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

in your head after including the jQuery library you'll prevent jQuery from having conflicts with Prototype

Comment: yes, i added these script in head..but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Sander is correct about the jQuery.noConflict() call. However I recommend putting it as the very last line of your jquery.js file.

Beyond that if the slide you're using uses $('#id') style jQuery selectors you're going to need to refactor all that code and where a $ is used replace is with jQuery

like:

```
jQuery('#id').sliderDoSomething();
```

Comment: i added jQuery.noConflict() at the end of the jquery.js file and used jQuery(document).ready(function() { as shown in question. but no change in ie 8 & 9